# Using NVL failing in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, nvl

Why is the following script:

```
INSERT INTO PLAYER(CURR_POSITION, USR_ID, PLAYER_TEAM_ID)
VALUES (NVL('', '1234456777'), '223233333333', (SELECT TEAM_ID FROM TEAM WHERE P_T_CD = '1111111'));
```

Gives me this error:

```
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (TIMSR.T_IR_R_246) violated - parent key not found
```

Whereas, when I structure my NVL statement like:

```
NVL('11111111111', '1234456777')...
```

It works without problems.

I am trying to use the NVL function so that if my first parameter is null then use the second one.

Comment: I'm guessing that `'1234456777'` isn't a valid value.  Are you remembering that `''` is the same a `NULL` in Oracle?

Comment: Yes, I intentionally included `''` for the purpose of testing so that it gets the second value which is a valid value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff actually, you're right. I was using invalid value. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: In other words, it is not NVL that isn't working, but 1234456777 doesn't exist in a referenced table.

Comment: @Littlefoot Correct

Answer (score 2):

One of the values that you are trying to insert fails a constraint validation. Check what constraint `IMSR.T_IR_R_246` corresponds to, and you will know which of the fields is causing the issue.

Also, please note that this part of your statement does not make sense :

```
NVL('', '1234456777')
```

As Oracle considers the empty string as a `NULL` value, the above expression will always return `'1234456777'`, hence what's the point of using `NVL` ?

You stated that when you change this expression to `NVL('11111111111', '1234456777')` then the query runs fine. This shows that the issue comes from the `'1234456777'` value, that corresponds to the first column that you insert (`CURR_POSITION`). Change that part of the statement and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for your informative response. I am building a dynamic stored procedure which will take inputs and the `NVL` function will determine which one to use for the insert statement.

Comment: @samg in this case I would say that the issue comes from your test data...